# MacOS - How do I programatically position image views next to each other?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Inside the main view of my MacOS app, I am trying to layout a bunch of image views next to each other.

The logic I am using is that the first sub view has its `leadingAnchor` set as the `leadingAnchor` of the main view, and every subsequent sub view has its `leadingAnchor` set as the `trailingAnchor` of the previous sub view.

```
            let imgWidth :CGFloat = 100, imgHeight :CGFloat = 100
            var leadingAnchor = self.view.leadingAnchor

            for /*loop logic*/ {

                let img: NSImage = funcToGetImage()
                var imgView = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: img.size))
                imgView.image = img

                self.view.addSubview(imgView)

                imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: imgWidth).isActive = true
                imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: imgHeight).isActive = true

                imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true

                leadingAnchor = imgView.trailingAnchor

            }
```

However I see only one image, and not a bunch of them positioned next to each other as I expected.

Am new to Swift/Xcode/MacOs development. What am I missing?

Edit:

If I replace the lines

```
var imgView = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: img.size))
imgView.image = img
```

with

```
imgView = NSImageView(image: img)
```

I don't see anything at all.

Edit2:
Replacing

```
var imgView = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: img.size))
```

with

```
var imgView = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: 0), size: img.size))

x += 100
```

did the trick.

Comment: "However I see only one image"  Obviously, you all position them at .zero.  I suggest you go back to a book and read about Control Flow.  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120

Comment: See edit. (I am not struggling with control flow logic here, but with displaying/positioning views)

Answer (score 0):

Based on El Tomato's comment, I replaced

```
var imgView = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(origin: .zero, size: img.size))
```

with

```
var imgView = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: 0), size: img.size))

x += 100
```

That did the trick.